# UnitTest Error Controller in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Iam a fan of 100% code coverage, but i have no idea how to test the ErrorController in Zend Framework.

It is no problem to test the 404Action and the errorAction:

```
    public function testDispatchErrorAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/error/error');
        $this->assertResponseCode(200);
        $this->assertController('error');
        $this->assertAction('error');
    }

    public function testDispatch404()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/error/errorxxxxx');
        $this->assertResponseCode(404);
        $this->assertController('error');
        $this->assertAction('error');
    }
```

But how to test for an application error (500)?
maybe i need something like this?

```
public function testDispatch500()
{
    throw new Exception('test');

    $this->dispatch('/error/error');
    $this->assertResponseCode(500);
    $this->assertController('error');
    $this->assertAction('error');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I was struggling with this today and couldn't find a good answer anywhere else so I'll go ahead and post what I did to solve this problem.  The answer is actually really simple.

Point your dispatch to an action that will result in a thrown exception.

My application throws an error when a get request is made to a JSON end point, so I used one of those to test this.

```
   /**
   * @covers  ErrorController::errorAction
   */
    public function testErrorAction500() {
        /**
         * Requesting a page that doesn't exist returns the proper error message 
         */
        $this->dispatch('/my-json-controller/json-end-point');
        $body = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
        $this->assertResponseCode('500');
        $this->assertContains('Application error',$body);
    }
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind having an action just for testing, you could just create an action that only throws an error and point to that action in your unit test.

```
public function errorAction() {
    throw new Exception('You should not be here');
}
```

Then your test would look like this:

```
   /**
   * @covers  ErrorController::errorAction
   */
    public function testErrorAction500() {
        /**
         * Requesting a page that doesn't exist returns the proper error message 
         */
        $this->dispatch('/my-error-controller/error');
        $body = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
        $this->assertResponseCode('500');
        $this->assertContains('Application error',$body);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very familiar with this subject, but I'd manipulate this behavior with a custom ErrorHandler plugin (extend the original, and pretend that an exception was thrown). Maybe it's possible to register it only for one test.